# MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVEのサンプリング周波数

Tags: android

※[Qiitaにも同じ質問を投稿しております。](https://qiita.com/voibow/questions/a27e1e0ec26414c267ca)

JavaでAndroidスマホアプリを作っております。
MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVEのサンプリング周波数をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
オーダーで結構です。調べる方法までわかればベストです。

Comment: モデルによるです。それぞれのスペックでTouch Sampling Rateを調べると分かります。

Answer (score 0):

Ricky Mo様へ：コメント頂き深謝します。この情報により解決できました。具体的には、GooglePlayに、MovementRateを計測できるアプリがあり実測できました。因みに私の端末は、100Hzオーダでした。